# How to set the content of a markup called "text" with lxml.objectify?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, lxml.objectify

I am trying to parse an XML File in python with lxml.objectify, modify the text from `<ns:text>` and then put back together the XML.

This is a short overview of my XML file:

```
<ns:map xmlns:ns="...">
    <ns:topics>
        <ns:topic>
            <ns:text>HI</ns:text>
        </ns:topic>
        <ns:topic>
            <ns:text>HELLO</ns:text>
        </ns:topic>
    </ns:topics>
</ns:map>
```

I parsed the XML and retrieved the topic in topics. I tried to change the "HI" text into "test" for `<ns:text>` in the first topic.

```
from lxml import objectify as obj
from lxml import etree

root= obj.parse(xmlFileName)
root.topics.topic[0].text = 'test'
obj_xml= etree.tostring(root, encoding="unicode", pretty_print=True)
print(obj_xml)
```

I supposed this would be the outcome:

```
<ns:map xmlns:ns="...">
    <ns:topics>
        <ns:topic>
            <ns:text>test</ns:text>
        </ns:topic>
        <ns:topic>
            <ns:text>HELLO</ns:text>
        </ns:topic>
    </ns:topics>
</ns:map>
```

but the `.text` is a read-only attribute and not my `<ns:text>`. I can't access my `<ns:text>` to change the text.

I have been reading a lot of tutorials with lxml.objectify but I can't find something similar to my problem.

PS: I cannot change the name of the markup. It's a generated XML.

Thank you,
Elena

Comment: If you have a solution, please post it as an answer. Do not add the solution in the question.

Comment: Oh right, I didn't know where to put :) I will change it

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I can access and change my text doing this:

`root.topics.topic[0]["text"] = "test"`